# sqlalchemy apache mod_wsgi crash with pyramid

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am running a basic Pyramid application with apache mod_Wsgi. My application setup seems Ok since I can access the home Pyramid template under Apache.

As soon as I issue a request to this app, the apache process crashes with 'premature end of script headers - segmentation fault'. This is how the sqlalchemy code looks for the request. (I've added this code to _*views.*_py itself since I am trying to create a RESTful framework without the use of models.)

```
try:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'entering sql execute'
            value=session.execute(s)
            for row in value:
                    listofclients.append(row[0])
            return listofclients
            session.close()
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError, exc:
            print >> sys.stderr, exc.message
```

I can see 'entering sql execute' in the apache error log. Immediately after which the process crashes. Commenting out the execute statement and returning sample values works.
Running this app under pserve provided by pyramid works like a charm.

Any help why Apache does not like the execute statment?
Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the mod_wsgi FAQ about process crashes.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes

The most probably cause being:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

To get a better idea use a debugger to capture a stack trace:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB

Comment: Expat libraries are ok. The test mentioned on the wiki passed. The WSGIApplicationGroup directive is set to %{GLOBAL} and I can verify from the request headers the application is set to ''. Dont really see any anomaly in the gdb trace. I tried using cx_Oracle.connect directly and it failed with seg fault again. Threading=true didnt help there as well. Cx_oracle seems the culprit but don't really know what to check.

Comment: On further inspection gdb shows the following message when a crash occcurs - ORA-24550: signal received: [si_signo=11] [si_errno=0] [si_code=1] [si_int=-522379924] [si_ptr=0x7fffe0dd1d6c] [si_addr=(nil)] Nothing on google has so far helped on this.

Answer (score 1):

Following Graham's suggestion and carefully examining the GDB backtrace of the crashed process, it turns out there was a ldap module which was interfering with the cx_Oracle connect string. the ldap_search_str() was the culprit.

Disabling the ldap modules fixed the issue.